# variable in reqwest http get request

Tags: rust, reqwest

Im trying to make a program in rust that will send a http req with reqwest for every line in a file, and have that line be apart of the get request.

```
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in reader.lines() {
        request::get("https://www.example.com/@{}", line)
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

when I try this and variations of it, it says that reqwest::get only takes one parameter and I've given two.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to [format!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/fn.format.html#) the url request. For example:

```rust
request::get(format!("https://www.example.com/@{}", line))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator) to unwrap the line (which is a `Result`) and use [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) to concatenate the strings.

```
request::get(format!("https://www.example.com/@{}", line?))
```